# Repo - code mismatch, some code is lacking

Tags: git, github

I merged master branch into dev branch, they should be the same. In source tree, they have the latest commit the same, so everything looks ok. Both branches are in origin.

But when I use `git checkout dev` in my project, I lack some code, as if it was before the merging.

In bitbucket, when I change branch to dev, the code looks ok. So why the hell do I lack it in my project then?

I tried `git pull` but I'm getting everything-up-to-date. `Git status` doesn't show anything either.

What's wrong?

Comment: Could it be possible that you have a detached head?

Comment: Did you find a solution in the end?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your local branch `dev` is not tracking the remote branch `dev`.

To check which remote branch each of your local branch is tracking, execute the command:

```
git branch -lvv
```

If, in the list of branches you get, your local branch `dev` is not tracking your remote branch `dev`, you might want to configure your local branch `dev` to track the remote branch `dev`. You can do this using the command

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=upstream/dev dev
```

given your remote is `upstream`.